# Counting images hit on AMP pages

Tags: reporting, amp-html, counting

Is it possible to count a hit for each image seen by a user (when they scroll the page) on a AMP page just like it's possible to count a hit on a carrousel for each image scrolled for example? 
If so could you please let me know how? 
Thank you so much for your precious help. 
Best

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely you can use amp-analytics and set up a trigger for when an image is visible and use a selector to target the specific image. Please see https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-analytics/?referrer=ampproject.org#triggers.

Alternatively, you can use [amp-pixel](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-pixel/) and include that very close to the image. When the amp-pixel is in view, it will fire a request to the endpoint specified on the tag.